# Javascript: How do I make an icon appear when mouseover selected text? (like an IE Accelerator)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I highlight some text on the page, and as I mouseover the selection, I want a clickable icon to appear. When I click this icon, I would like a context style menu to appear.

This only has to work in Chrome, as I'm building it for a Chrome Extension.

The behaviour I'm trying to create is actually around in IE - they call it an Accelerator.

Take a look at this feature, by opening IE and selecting some text and hovering the cursor over it.

Does any one know how I'd achieve this?

I'm happy to use any library, or write bespoke code.

Thanks.

EDIT: Feel free to down vote me if you think this isn't a very good question, but I'd appreciate any constructive comments to help me make the question better or direct me to a better forum. Thanks guys!

Comment: Those are called accelerators.

Comment: You just need to handle selection events and create an absolutely-positioned element.

Comment: Ah thanks SLaks! I'll do a bit of Googling around that.

Comment: I vaguely wonder if `::selection:hover` would work...

Comment: Thanks Kolink - I'll try that out. Do you know why people are voting me down for this question?

Comment: What SLaks said. Listen for the selection event, and wrap the selection in a wrapper element. Add a hidden absolutely positioned link icon inside it and toggle the display of the icon on mouseover of your wrapper element.

Comment: @Ev.: Your question shows very little research effort.  My first comment should have been relatively obvious; which part are you having trouble with / asking about?